# PowerShell script to copy jpg files from one folder to another by creating two subfolders with the same name

Tags: powershell

I am in need of some assistance, I am new to PowerShell and am trying to use it to make some of my work easier. I am writing a PowerShell script to copy JPG files from one location (C:\Pictures\People\People) and moving them to a new location.

The issue is that in this new location I need to create a folder with the same name as the JPG and then another subfolder with the same name again as the JPG.

So I need to move images from `C:\Pictures\People\People` which I will call JPG_Image to `C:\Pictures\JPG_Name\JPG_Name\'JPG_Image'`

So far I found and have been working with this:

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\Pictures\People\People"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Pictures\"
   # Find all files matching *.JPG in the folder specified
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.jpg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ChildPath = Join-Path -Path $_.Name.Replace('.jpg','') -ChildPath $_.Name
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Destination = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $ChildPath
   # Create the directory if it doesn't already exits
        if( -not ( Test-Path -Path $Destination.Directory.FullName ) ){
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination.Directory.FullName
            }
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination.FullName
        }
```

Comment: And whats your issue? Code looks ok on first sight, of course you can resolve things another way

Comment: The issue is that it only creates one folder rather than two. Because I need a subfolder inside the original folder it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this harder on yourself than needs be.

Some enhancements to your code:

- Add switch `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmd so you do not also get DirectoryInfo objects
- To get the filename without extension, there is a property `.BaseName`
- `Join-Path` returns a string, no need to cast that into a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object
- If you add `-Force` to the `New-Item` cmd, there is no need to check if a folder already exists, because that will make the cmdlet either create a new folder or return the existing DirectoryInfo object.
  Because we don't need that object (and the console output from it), we can just throw that away using `$null = New-Item ...`

Putting it all together:

```
$SourceFolder = "C:\Pictures\People\People"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Pictures"

# Find all files matching *.JPG in the folder specified
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter '*.jpg' -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Join-Path simply returns a string containing the combined path
        # The BaseName property is the filename without extension
        $ChildPath   = Join-Path -Path $_.BaseName -ChildPath $_.BaseName
        $Destination = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $ChildPath
        # Create the directory if it doesn't already exits
        # Using -Force will not give an error if the folder already exists
        $null = New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    }
```